# In my application System.data.OracleClient is not coming

Tags: sql-server

In my application, on namesapce System.Data.OracleClient is not coming, what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import any namespace, you have to make sure you have added a reference to the appropriate DLL that contains the namespace (and classes within) that you want you use.

Comment: In my case, `System.Data.OracleClient` was not available in the **Add Reference** dialog. To resolve this, on the **Application** page of my Project properties, I changed **Target framework** from **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile** to **.NET Framework 4**.